# Try/catch for Illegal Characters

Tags: powershell, error-handling, try-catch, illegal-characters

#### Problem and Details

I am working with custom error handling and one of the errors I'm having difficulty catching is the "Illegal Characters in Path". I have a custom function that is meant to look through the path string for such illegal characters and throws a custom error when they are found. But I am finding that depending on the illegal character, the `Test-Path` cmdlet throws the error first.

I have tried thing like:

```
try {
    Test-Path $path
} catch {
    "Custom Message"
}
```

Which will sorta do what I want... but not fully.

```
function isPathValid {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter]
        [string]$path
    )
    if (!($path -match "[^a-zA-Z\s]") -OR ($path -match "[^\<\>\*\?\`"\``\`|]") {
        throw "customException"
    } else {
        return $true
    }
}
```

Which doesn't really work... but if I change the second part out to match against them individually, I can catch most.

#### Question

Is it possible to create a `-match` check for characters such as `< > * ? | " ``? Or is there a more intuitive way to catch these characters?

Assuming the above is possible, is there a way to ensure I can use that to catch the problem before the `Test-Path` cmdlet does?

Comment: Why catch it before `Test-Path`? Isn't that kind of what `Test-Path -IsValid` is for?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Because I am apparently mad in the head. My train of thought was to catch special characters (like wild cards) so that the user couldn't input them, whether the path was valid or not.

Comment: @Brandon: Very much awkward thought indeed.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician: I have the default `ErrorPreference` set to "Stop" and this seems to cause the application to crash stating that have an "unhandled exception". Gonna try something...

Comment: @TheMadTechnician: No, the idea I had failed. It turns out that even if I encase the `Test-Path` in its own Try-Catch, it still breaks due to that error. I discovered the error when I accidentally entered a `|` instead of a `\\` and even though it will display my custom error, it still breaks with the above error

Comment: So how exactly does what TheMadTechnician suggest not work for you? Why do you need to catch it before?

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you running? Because even with `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` set, I don't crash when I try `Test-Path -Path 'C:\Temp|FakeFile.txt' -IsValid`, I just get `$false` (or `False` output to the screen), no crashes in both the ISE and console.

Answer (score 2):

You could continue using `Test-Path` with the `IsValid` switch

```
$path = "C:\Path\To\Valid\File.extension"
$isPathValid = Test-Path -Path $path -IsValid # True

$path = "C:\InvalidPath<>"
$isPathValid = Test-Path -Path $path -IsValid # False

$path = "C:\Path?\ValidFileName"
$isPathValid = Test-Path -Path $path -IsValid # False

$path = "C:\InvalidPath\InvalidFileName?"
$isPathValid = Test-Path -Path $path -IsValid # False
```

or potentially use [Path.GetInvalidPathChars](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars(v=vs.110).aspx/html) or [PathGetInvalidFileNameChars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars(v=vs.110).aspx) / incorporate into your own validation

```
$path = "C:\Path\To\Valid\File.extension"
$isPathValid = $path.IndexOfAny([System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidPathChars()) -lt 0 # True

$path = "C:\InvalidPath<>"
$isPathValid = $path.IndexOfAny([System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidPathChars()) -lt 0 # False

# Note difference between this return compared to Test-Path above
$path = "C:\Path?\ValidFileName"
$isPathValid = $path.IndexOfAny([System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidPathChars()) -lt 0 # True

$path = "C:\Path?\ValidFileName"
$isPathValid = $path.IndexOfAny([System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars()) -lt 0 # False

$path = "C:\InvalidPath\InvalidFileName?"
$isPathValid = $path.IndexOfAny([System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars()) -lt 0 # False
```

Comment: I would have suggested using `[System.IO.Path]` as well. The invalids are already known so might as well use them.